# Supporting shadow/concealer tokens in .NET Core 2+

Tags: c#, security, jwt, asp.net-core-2.2, .net-core-3.0

I have a security setup running and upon a login, the user get the produced token to be used for each subsequent call. If they tamper with the payload, the signature will bark, so the system is secured as such.

However, I trust that there are malicious users with more brains than me and in order to make their challenge more interesting, I want to limit the amount of info being exposed. Instead of emitting the claims, I want to keep them internally and only expose a guid as a shadow token (I believe that's the right term for a token that is rather a pointer to the actual token, concealing it).

An option is to develop custom validators and introduce storage of actual tokens in the DB for lookup using the concealers. It's quite some work and since the procedure is good-practice I would expect ready to use facilitation of that feature in the framework.

Regrettably, I haven't found anything about that when googling. I would need a pointer or two on how to find info about it (or confirmation that it doesn't exist). Since it's a deep and complex issue, it might be my ignorance preventing me from find the right search terms.

Comment: It's probably safer and easier just to encrypt the JWT (aka JWE), take a look at this for example https://www.scottbrady91.com/C-Sharp/JSON-Web-Encryption-JWE-in-dotnet-Core

Comment: @DavidG Ah, there you go. This term was not a part of my googling at all. I simply assumed this strict no-show-no-tell policy. Thanks. Of course, that still requires implementation of custom validators but at least I won't have to fool around in the DB.